# Training my simple model for colored images instead of grayscale

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, classification

I'm new to Python and Deep Learning with Keras. With some tutorials online for cat vs non-cat classification, I was able to compile this simple training code for my classification. However, my target application is **fire** detection so I think I need to use color images instead of this grayscale version (+ is it going to help?!). In other words, to get rid of `img = img.convert('L')` and train with colors on.

While I was trying to increase the number of channels to `3`, I encountered this error:

```
training_images = np.array([i[0] for i in training_data]).reshape(-1, IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE, 3)
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (300,300,3) into shape (300,300)
```

How can I solve this error?

Here is my original training code:

```
from keras.models import Sequential, load_model
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Flatten
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers.normalization import BatchNormalization
from PIL import Image
from random import shuffle, choice
import numpy as np
import os

IMAGE_SIZE = 256
IMAGE_DIRECTORY = './data/test_set'

def label_img(name):
  if name == 'cats': return np.array([1, 0])
  elif name == 'notcats' : return np.array([0, 1])

def load_data():
  print("Loading images...")
  train_data = []
  directories = next(os.walk(IMAGE_DIRECTORY))[1]

  for dirname in directories:
    print("Loading {0}".format(dirname))
    file_names = next(os.walk(os.path.join(IMAGE_DIRECTORY, dirname)))[2]

    for i in range(200):
      image_name = choice(file_names)
      image_path = os.path.join(IMAGE_DIRECTORY, dirname, image_name)
      label = label_img(dirname)
      if "DS_Store" not in image_path:
        img = Image.open(image_path)
        img = img.convert('L')
        img = img.resize((IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        train_data.append([np.array(img), label])

  return train_data

def create_model():
  model = Sequential()
  model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size = (3, 3), activation='relu', 
                   input_shape=(IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE, 1)))
  model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
  model.add(BatchNormalization())
  model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3,3), activation='relu'))
  model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
  model.add(BatchNormalization())
  model.add(Conv2D(128, kernel_size=(3,3), activation='relu'))
  model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
  model.add(BatchNormalization())
  model.add(Conv2D(128, kernel_size=(3,3), activation='relu'))
  model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
  model.add(BatchNormalization())
  model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3,3), activation='relu'))
  model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
  model.add(BatchNormalization())
  model.add(Dropout(0.2))
  model.add(Flatten())
  model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
  model.add(Dropout(0.2))
  model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
  model.add(Dense(2, activation = 'softmax'))

  return model

training_data = load_data()
training_images = np.array([i[0] for i in training_data]).reshape(-1, IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE, 1)
training_labels = np.array([i[1] for i in training_data])

print('creating model')
model = create_model()
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
print('training model')
model.fit(training_images, training_labels, batch_size=50, epochs=10, verbose=1)
model.save("model.h5")
```

Comment: if your images are already colored(RGB) , just comments #img = img.convert('L')
       # img = img.resize((IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE), Image.ANTIALIAS)

Comment: Not that simple I guess. How about `input_shape=(IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE, 1)` and others?

Comment: i think you need to preprocess images to fit the network, otherwise you will get the missmatching shapes

Answer (score 0):

for transforming your images, you have to duplicate the channels of your single image. Note that you need only the "convered image afte duplicating the channels.
you can write a function that does the following and pass it to the comprehension list

```
>>> img = np.random.randint(low=0,high=255, size=(330,330))
>>> converted=np.empty([330,330,3], dtype=int)
>>> red = img.copy()
>>> blue = img.copy()
>>> green = img.copy()
>>> converted[:,:,0]= red
>>> converted[:,:,1]= blue
>>> converted[:,:,2]= green
>>> from PIL import Image
>>> s = Image.fromarray(converted,'RGB')
>>> s.save("rand_image.png")
>>> s.show()
```

Comment: Well, my images are already colored. I meant how to change the code to accept colors. Right now it converts them to grayscale if you see.

Comment: sorry, my bad...you want them to be grayscale?

Comment: you want to change training_data samples into a 300,300,3 shape from 300,300?

Comment: Yes right. Get rid of `img = img.convert('L')` and train with colors on.